# How can I add repeated values to an array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array `@genotypes = "TT AG TT AG...."` and want to add a spike to it (e.g. 20 x TT) to make a new array.

I can obviously `push` "TT" into the array 20 times - but is there a simpler way of doing this?  (ie. not `@newarray = push @genotypes ("TT", "TT", "TT",......20 times!);`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
@newlist = (@genotypes, ('TT') x 20);
```

Yes, it is an `x`.

See [Multiplicative Operators in perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators).

Answer (score 6):

The repetition operator is the most obvious way.
You could also use `map`:

```
@newarray = (@genotypes, map 'TT', 1..20);
```

Answer (score 4):

There's also the `foreach` way of pushing multiple identical values to an array:

```
push @newarray, 'TT' foreach (1..20);
```

Comment: And the shorter form `push @newarray, 'TT' for (1..20);`